# Python to fetch LDAP credentials from JSON file

Tags: python, json, ldap

I have the following line of code in a python script to bind to LDAP using my credentials(assuming username is "abcdef", and password is "123456":

```
l.simple_bind_s("domain\abcdef", "123456")
```

Works fine when I run the script and do queries.

However, how can I replace the hardcoded credentials to be read from a JSON file instead?

I currently wrote this JSON file and named it creds.json:

```
{
    "username": "domain\\abcdef",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

Im new to coding, and any help would be great to be able to import the credentials to my python script that are stored in a json file. What would i need to do to the python script to make this work?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a minimalist example of how to get values from a json file.

```
import json

with open('creds.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


user = data['username']
pwd =  data['password']

print(user)
print(pwd)
```

I take from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/4172067

Comment: I assume I put that in my python script, which defines "user" and "pwd". What do I need to do to my existing python line that has the credentials hardcoded? Thanks!

Comment: You can use that: `l.simple_bind_s(user, pwd)`

Comment: That worked beautifully!!! I will share entire script here later for everyone :-) thanks Thiago for all your help!!