# Import credentials from a json file to a python variable

Tags: python, json, environment-variables, dotenv

I want to import my credentials from a .env file as this is a much more secure way.

I cant find instructions on the documentation: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/
and similar question cant also help: [Python to fetch LDAP credentials from JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421388/python-to-fetch-ldap-credentials-from-json-file)

but basically I have and json variable ard code that it is currently working:

```
payload = {
    'client_id': "12345",
    'client_secret': 'a1234567803972de4472',
    'refresh_token': 'c123456755647353200eae76387d8c47f52',
    'grant_type': "refresh_token",
    'f': 'json' }
```

*Changed for security*

I want to have those in a .env file and to import it just like that.

```
res = requests.post(auth_url, data=payload, verify=False)
access_token = res.json()['access_token']
```

thanks in andvance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `.env` file is in the root of your project.

**Do Not** add the quotation string in the environment variable value.

**Do Not** add extra spaces between key=value

Your `.env` file should look like the sample below.

```
client_id=12345
client_secret=a1234567803972de4472
```

Lastly, in your python file, to load the `.env` file.

```
from dotenv import dotenv_values

config = dotenv_values(".env")
```